# Save multiple values in one field (Django)

Tags: python, django, model

## The problem:

I have a model, which is referencing the basic User model of django. Right now, if I submit the form Django updates my database by replacing the existing data with the new one. I want to be able to access both of them. (In weight and date field)

## Models file:

I saw other posts here, where they solved a problem by specifying a foreign key, but that doesn't solve it for me.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      weight = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
      height = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
      date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
      def __str__(self):
          return self.user.username

      @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
      def save_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
      if created:
      Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

## Views file:

This is where I save the data that I get from my form called WeightForm

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from users import models
from users.models import Profile
from .forms import WeightForm

def home(request):
    form = WeightForm()
    if request.is_ajax():
       profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id = request.user.id)
       form = WeightForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return JsonResponse({
            'msg': 'Success'
        })
       
    
return render(request, 'Landing/index.html',{'form':form})
```

## What I tried:

I used to have a OneToOneField relation with this model, but as you can see I changed it to foreignkey, according to answers I saw on this site.

Thanks if you've gotten this far in my mess :D

Comment: I could not understand "*I want to be able to access both of them. (In weight and date field)*"

Comment: Well, I want to be able to store multiple values for a single user. Like he could have 10 weight values and so on

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understood exactly what you mean by "I want to be able to access both of them. (In weight and date field)" but I guess you want user to be able to see their previous data of weight and Date also, so you can try doing this:

In your models.py do try doing this,

```
class Profile(models.Model):
      user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      height = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
      def __str__(self):
          return self.user.username

class UserData(models.Model):
      Data_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      user_id = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      weight = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
      date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

then u can have seperate forms for both the models and use them combined.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a workaround

1. Create new model which would include something like "version"
2. Reference to version with foreign key

   ```
    class ProfileChange(models.Model):
        Date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

         @classmethod
         def create(cls):
            object = cls()
            return object


    class Profile(models.Model):
        version = models.ForeignKey(ProfileChange,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ```

Unfortunately, you could see only one ProfileChange a day. If you want to see more of them, instead of `models.DataField` use `models.IntegerField`

Comment: Well, I gave it a go, but it does the same thing. Replaces the existing values in the database

Comment: can you give a try to new solution?